# Setting rack environment for staging on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

if `RACK_ENV` is set to be
production, then it works ok. If we set it to staging by

```
heroku config:set RACK_ENV=myapp
```

then we see error with cache `Session::DalliStore#get: Unable to
unmarshal value: undefined class/module PiFinancialPlannersFact`

I would like to set `RACK_ENV=myapp`, so that
config.yml's staging section can be used, how it is possible could any body tell me.

Comment: Did you mean `RACK_ENV=staging`?

Comment: yes i mean heroku config:add RACK_ENV=staging --app appname

Answer (score 0):

How about using .env with Foreman?

`RACK_ENV=myapp`

see also https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars